# node.js server not running

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to learn node.js, but I'm having trouble getting the simple server to run on `localhost:8888`.

Here is the code for server.js:

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function(request, response) {
response.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type": "text/plain"});
response.write("Hello World");
response.end();
}).listen(8888);
```

server.js runs without errors, and trying `netstat -an | grep 8888` from terminal returns

```
tcp4       0      0  *.8888                 *.*                    LISTEN
```

However, when I go to localhost:8888 in a browser, it says that it cannot be found.

I've looked at all the related questions, and nothing has worked so far. I've tried different ports, etc. I know that my router blocks incoming traffic on port 8888, but shouldn't that not matter if I'm trying to access it locally? I've run tomcat servers on this port before, for example. Thanks so much for your help!

**node.js version:** v0.6.15 
**OS:** Mac OS 10.6.8

Comment: have you tried http://127.0.0.1:8888?

Comment: Works for me. Did you perhaps enter a wrong URL?

Comment: are you running a software firewall?  Does this url work in your browser: `http://127.0.0.1`?

Comment: another thing that occurred to my mind - if your browser is using a proxy that doesn't have an exception rule for local addresses, it may be trying to access it with a proxy. You could try to telnet to that port.

Comment: how can you say it works for you?

Comment: @Esailija — By copy / pasting the code and trying it on their own machine. This should be a comment though.

Comment: @Quentin It is given that the code works but the question is more of a specific configuration that he cannot even know and say that it works for him :P

Comment: No, if i had a specific config, i'd let you know. OS X Darwin, works with and without OS X Firewall.

Comment: Don't miss the firewall's prompt though.

Comment: @FlorianSalihovic I mean you cannot know the OP's config and specifics that actually cause the problem. You are saying it works for you based on the code only, which isn't the issue here at all.

Comment: Well, i'm assuming if you adress localhost, you are on one machine, which also runs the server. There aren't too many pitfalls. I'm on the same OS and running Node v0.6.18. So, unless you don't provide more specifics on the scenario, there aren't many possibilities other then running it on our own machines.

Comment: @FlorianSalihovic agree that this is more of a serverfault/superuser question than specific code question, I mean how much can be wrong with the code of textbook node.js hello world example?

Comment: Well, why should the book be wrong when it don't run on your machine but it works on others?

Comment: Thanks for the advice, everyone. 127.0.0.1:8888 times out, as does 127.0.0.1. I can ping 127.0.0.1, but 127.0.0.1:8888 is an unknown host and does not resolve. I realize now that this is not a code-specific post -- sorry for posting it in the wrong place. I'm still getting the hang of Stack Exchange. I'll look for an answer in Superuser.

Comment: I have almost a similar problem where the browser downloads the file instead of displaying it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code works--I just tried it and navigated to localhost:8888 and saw the expected output.

It's possible that you have a firewall that's too restrictive or you have a bad install of Node.js.

Comment: Yeah, it seems that way. Thanks! I'll look for a fix elsewhere.